# In Malloreon, Polgara suppresses a soap bar... how is that?

Tags: the-malloreon

Ctuchik learns a final lesson, one cannot "destroy" anything, because it goes against the purpose of the universe. How does Polgara destroy the soap bar her father created in the beginning of the Malloreon?

Comment: +1 for the name - how's business Silk? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's hard to say since it's a very brief mention, and unfortunately, David Eddings is no longer around to ask.

> "Not mine, it won't," she said, taking the cake of soap out of his hand. She held it up, balanced neatly on her palm. Then she blew on it with a slight puff, and it instantly vanished.

But, since Belgarath casually produced it in the first place, I suspect that he probably built it out of constituent materials around him (much as Polgara was doing manually) and she simply returned it to such materials. It's no more "unmaking" than burning someone to turn them back into carbon is.

Comment: _than burning someone to turn them back into carbon_ that got dark fast!

Comment: @BinaryWorrier: Well, the charring will do that. :-D

Comment: Interestingly, she also doesn't use any sort of Word. When Chtuchik gets rekt, he says "Be not!". Perhaps it i possible, in some fashion, to 'uncreate' thing so long as you on't make it too obvious to the Universe that it's what you're doing.

Comment: @DanielB I think Polgara is too classy to say **"Bathe Not!"** or the like...  ;D  I'm imagining she just atomized it in some way, so if you took a really close look there'd be soap particles floating about.

Comment: @DanielB The actual word makes no difference to the magic.   The puff of air and sound past her lips, coupled with a firm desire that the soap be elsewhere would result in the soap being elsewhere.   If she had actually desired the "unmaking" of the soap, the universe wouldn't have cared if she was being subtle.

Comment: It has been many years since I have read those books.   Was the quote from a flashback early in her training?  The tone seems to put it later when she really just puts up with Belgarath rather than actively learning anything from him.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson: It's from a scene where she and Durnik are making soap, and Belgarath complains that she's squandering her talents. He creates a bar of soap with magic to try to show her how pointless it is doing it by hand.